# Node.js newly created buffer already has data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a weird problem with node.js buffers.

```
this.m_aucState0 = new Buffer(256)
this.m_aucState = new Buffer(256)

console.log(this.m_aucState0)
```

This exact code (in that order) returns:

```
<Buffer f8 6e 03 01 01 00 00 00 90 4a 63 00 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 90 78 06 01 01 00 00 00 c8 78 06 01 01 00 00 00 95 1c 00 ...>
```

I haven't added any data to it yet, why does it have data?

Comment: The buffer type is pretty basic, and in general when a system provides newly allocated memory it makes no effort to cleanse whatever was previously residing there. It looks like Node.js makes no assumptions about how you want to use the buffer and does not set the block of memory to zero for you.

to be more specific, Node.js is powered by V8, which is written in C++, where clearing memory on allocation is optional -- see calloc vs malloc

Comment: Oh. Now I have to include `.fill(0)` to all buffers I create.

Comment: Well, only if you care about what is in the buffer before you start writing to it.